# Debugging step in and step out is slower in VS2015

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

i am using VS2015 and developing a UWP project. when i try to debug my code by using breakpoint, it takes upto 2 second for debugging a single line. Whether i need to change any settings to make it faster?

Note: I tried to set the below options

```
1.Uncheck the option -> Enable Property evaluation and other implicit function calls.

2.Check the option -> Use Managed Compatibility code.

3.Check the option -> Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance
```

I tried to set the above options, but still it makes slower while debugging. Is there any option will improve performance while debugging in VS2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please disable the symbols server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols.

A blog also shared us some suggestions which could make debugging faster:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/03/03/make-debugging-faster-with-visual-studio/

Comment: i was not clear with this blog, what to do with these symbols, how to disable loading symbols, if we disable it, then whether any problem will occur?

Comment: @venkatesan r, if you disable the option "Microsoft Symbol Servers ", and then debug your app, whether it could improve the performance? During debugging, it would load the symbols file, and some symbols were downloaded from this public servers, if you disable it, maybe you could get certain warning like "can't find the pdb file or can't load symbols " in the output window, but generally it would not impact the debugging.

Comment: You are welcome, venkatesan. If the reply is helpful, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks:)